# Making a plot of ${\rm Re}(z)+\ln|1−| $

Tags: plotting, syntax

Please, help me to make a plot of the complex expression ${\rm Re}(z)+\ln|1−| ≤ 1/2$

I tried this:

```
Plot[Rez + Log10[abs( 1 − )] ≤ 0.5, {z, -10, 10}
```

and

```
Plot[x + Log10[Sqrt[(1 - x)^2 + y^2]] <= 0.5, {x, -10, 10}, {y, -10, 10}]
```

What is my mistake?

The graph should look like this:

[image]

I'm using Mathematica 12.

Comment: `Plot[z = Exp[-I ϕ]; Re[Log[1 - z] + z], {ϕ, -10, 10}]`

Comment: thank you Louis!!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To get a plot that looks like the one in your post, you will not only have to correct your syntax errors, but use several of Mathematica's plotting options. The default options don't produce a plot anything like what you show. Here is one way to make the plot look fairly close to what you show:

```
Plot[With[{z = E^(I u)}, Re[z] + Log[Abs[1 - z]]], {u, -10, 10},
  PlotRange -> {Automatic, {-3, 1}},
  AspectRatio -> 1,
  AxesLabel -> (Style[#, 14] & /@ {"φ", "f"}),
  GridLines -> {Range[-10, 10, 1], Range[-3, 1, .2]},
  Frame -> True,
  FrameTicks -> {{Range[-3, 1, .2], Automatic}, {Range[-10, 10, 1], Automatic}},
  PlotLabel ->
    Style[TraditionalForm[HoldForm[Re[z] + ln[Abs[1 - z]] ≤ 1/2]], "TR", Black, 14],
  ImageSize -> Large]
```

[image: plot]

Comment: thank you so much!

Answer (score 3):

```
Clear["Global`*"]
```

Since you are only interested in real values for `ϕ`, use [`ComplexExpand`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ComplexExpand.html) to eliminate the [`Abs`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Abs.html) and make the function differentiable.

```
f[ϕ_] = 
 Re[z] + Log[Abs[1 - z]] /. z -> Exp[-I ϕ] // ComplexExpand // Simplify

(* Cos[ϕ] + 1/2 Log[2 - 2 Cos[ϕ]] *)
```

The maximum is

```
Maximize[f[ϕ], ϕ]

(* {1/2, {ϕ -> π/3}} *)
```

All maxima within the interval `-10 <= ϕ <= 10` are located at

```
max = Solve[{f[ϕ] == 1/2, -10 <= ϕ <= 10}, ϕ]

(* {{ϕ -> -((7 π)/3)}, {ϕ -> -((5 π)/3)}, {ϕ -> -(π/3)}, 
    {ϕ -> π/3}, {ϕ -> (5 π)/3}, {ϕ -> (7 π)/3}} *)
```

The finite minimum are located at

```
min = Solve[{f'[ϕ] == 0, f''[ϕ] > 0, -10 <= ϕ <= 10}, ϕ]

(* {{ϕ -> -3 π}, {ϕ -> -π}, {ϕ -> π}, {ϕ -> 3 π}} *)
```

These minimum are

```
f[ϕ] /. min // Union

(* {-1 + Log[4]/2} *)
```

The plot is then

```
Plot[f[ϕ], {ϕ, -10, 10},
 Epilog -> {AbsolutePointSize[4],
   Red, Point[{ϕ, f[ϕ]} /. max],
   Blue, Point[{ϕ, f[ϕ]} /. min]}]
```

[image]

Comment: thank you very much

Answer (score 2):

As far as I know, inequalities represent regions. I use below two pieces of codes obtaining the same result, but differing from what the OP desired. Do I misunderstand something?

```
ComplexRegionPlot[Re[z] + Log[Abs[1 - z]] <= 1/2, {z, -10 - 10 I, 2 + 10 I}]
```

and

```
Re[z] + Log[Abs[1 - z]] <= 1/2 /. z -> x + I y // ComplexExpand
RegionPlot[%, {x, -10, 2}, {y, -10, 10}]
```

[image]

Comment: thank you for this